# Prevent value of 0 evaluating to false when using logical OR

Tags: javascript, boolean, logical-operators, short-circuiting

I am wondering if there was a way around this issue. I am currently storing a value in a variable like so:

```
Session['Score'] = 0;
```

Later I have an assignment like so:

```
Score = Session['Score'] || 'not set';
```

The problem is, when `Session['Score']` is set to `0` as above, JavaScript will interpret it as:

```
Score = false || 'not set';
```

which means `Score` will evaluate to `'not set'` instead of `0`!

How can I get around this issue?

Comment: why not use a ternary ? you could use a negative value instead btw.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Default_values_2):

```
let { Score = 'not set' } = Session;
```

If it's not set:

```js
const Session = { };
let { Score = 'not set' } = Session;
console.log( Score );
```

If it is set to any value other than `undefined`, including falsy ones:

```js
const Session = { Score: 0 };
let { Score = 'not set' } = Session;
console.log( Score );
```

Answer (score 6):

Nowadays you can use the [nullish coalescing operator (??)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator) instead of the logical OR. It is similar to the logical OR, except that it only returns the right-hand side when the left-hand side is nullish (`null` or `undefined`) instead of [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy).

```
score = Session['Score'] ?? 'not set';
```

---

Old answer:

The cleanest way is probably to set the value and then check if it is falsy but not equal to `0`

```
let score = Session['Score'];

if (!score && score !== 0) {
  score = 'not set';
}
```

As mentioned by [Patrick Roberts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53462705/prevent-value-of-0-stored-in-session-evaluating-to-false/53462793#comment93796985_53462793), you could also choose to use the [conditional (ternary) operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) in combination with the [`in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in) operator:

```
Score = 'Score' in Session ? Session.Score : 'not set'
```

Comment: `'Score' in Session ? Session.Score : 'not set'`?

Answer (score 1):

You could be more explicit about your intent by creating a few functions:

```
function getScore(s)
{
    var result = s["Score"];
    if (result == null) {
        result = 0;
    }
    return result;
}

function addScore(s, v)
{
    var result = s["Score"];
    if (result == null) {
        result = 0;
    }
    result += v;
    s["Score"] = result;
    return result;
}

var Session = {};
document.write("Score ");
document.write(getScore(Session));
document.write("<p/>");
addScore(Session, 10);
document.write("Score ");
document.write(getScore(Session));
```

Expected output:

```
Score 0

Score 10
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a string instead:

```
Session['Score'] = "0";

Score = Session['Score'] || 'not set';
```

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Really? Why? I thought that a string would fix it.

Comment: Really? You posted this as an answer without trying it first to see that it works?

Comment: I don't have the code, and I don't know the OP's context, so I can't test it.

Comment: `var Session = {};
Session['Score'] = "0";
var Score = parseInt(Session['Score']) || 'not set';
console.log(Score);` Seems simple enough to create some context there.

Comment: Wait a second. Look at my test https://web.edusercontent.com/d73ter2hovoc1fki8rqcb6m8dk/index.html

Comment: Do you see the difference between `"0" || "not set"` and `parseInt("0") || "not set"`?

Comment: Oh, yes - I should remove the `parseInt`

Comment: I still think this solution causes more problems than it solves. Now you can't just `Session.Score += ...` because now it's interpreted as string concatenation rather than addition, which makes everything else more verbose than necessary.